# How to fix this "if" statement

Tags: javascript

I don't really know the correct format to this if statement. I want it to count the frequency each word in my txt file was used.

```
function countWords(array, word, index) {
  var count = 0;
  var value = " "
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 0 && value == word)
      count++;
  }
}



if (getUserSelectionForm.problem.value == "pay") {
  countWords(working2DArray, "pay", 0)
  if (getUserSelectionForm.problem.value == "staffing") {
    countWords(working2DArray, "staffing", 0)
    if (getUserSelectionForm.problem.value == "hours") {
      countWords(working2DArray, "hours", 0)
      if (getUserSelectionForm.problem.value == "management") {
        countWords(working2DArray, "management", 0)
        console.log(countWords)
        document.getElementById('section2').innerHTML = "The selected word      appears " + countWords + " times in the array."
      }
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: `countWords` is a function and you are displaying it in `innerHTML`...

Comment: Hi! I edited your code by using a javascript beautifier that indents the code. When the code is indented is it much easier to see that you have missed the closing tags of the blocks.

Comment: Were any of these answers helpful in answering your question?  If so, then you should accept one.

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use multiple `IF` statements and use a switch statement instead.  Makes code much clearer and cleaner.

E.g.

```
switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

So:

```
var p = getUserSelectionForm.problem.value;

switch (p) {
    case 'pay':
        countWords(working2DArray, "pay", 0);
        break;
    case 'staffing':
        countWords(working2DArray, "staffing", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making three mistakes in code:

- You are missing some of the closing curly braces `}` of you if blocks.
- You do not `return` anything from function. You should return `count`.
- `countWords` is a function you don't need to display that. You need to display its result.

You can make your code much simpler. You don't need these `if` statements at all because you are passing the same value of `getUserSelectionForm.problem.value` to the function so directly pass it.

```
function countWords(array, word, index) {
   var count = 0;
   var value= " "
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if(array[i] == 0 && value == word)
         count++;
   }
   return count;
}
let word = getUserSelectionForm.problem.value
document.getElementById('section2').innerHTML = `The selected word appears ${countWords(working2DArray,word,0)} times in array`
```

If you want to only check for few items then use create a array of `"pay","staffing"...` and use `includes()` on it

```
let word = getUserSelectionForm.problem.value

if(["pay","staffing","hours","management"].includes(word)){     
    document.getElementById('section2').innerHTML = `The selected word appears ${countWords(working2DArray,word,0)} times in array` 
}
```

Comment: I do only want to check for a few items! Would the "let" still work when pulling from a txt file?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding , you want to trigger the function whenever problem.value ==='pay'||'staffing'||'hours'||'management' ,here is clearer version for your reference:

```
var problemValue = getUserSelectionForm.problem.value;
var isProblemValueMatch = ["pay", "staffing" ,"hours", "management"].includes(problemValue);
if (isProblemValueMatch  ) {
  var countWords = working2DArray.filter(function(v) {
    return v === problemValue;
   }).length;
  console.log(countWords)
  document.getElementById('section2').innerHTML = "The selected word appears " + countWords + " times in the array."
}
```

Comment: `["pay","staffing"...].includes(problemValue)` would be shorter I guess.

Comment: @MaheerAli You are right, edited , thanks for advising.